# Time complexity for solving linear congruences?

Tags: ds.algorithms, time-complexity, nt.number-theory

What is the best known algorithm to solve linear congruences of the form below?
$$a x + b \equiv 0 \space (n)$$

And what is the time complexity of it?

Comment: I think it is the same as the complexity of computing GCD. You can use the euclidean algorithm, but IIRC it is open if there is a better algorithm.

Comment: What does “ax+b≡(n)” mean?  Is it the same as “ax+b≡0 (mod n)”?